# How to configure the java client for couchbase to auto-reconnect?

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

How to configure the java client for couchbase to auto-reconnect?

Is it turned on by default? Also, it will be great if somebody can help to show how to do it using spring-data-couchbase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the 1.4.x and 2.x generations of Couchbase Java SDKs will auto-reconnect when a node is (re)introduced to the cluster through a rebalance event. Spring-data-couchbase being (currently) based on the 1.4.x SDK, it should transparently reconnect as well.

Comment: In case of server went down for few minutes and then come back up, will it auto-reconnect too?

Comment: to add to my answer, you still have to detect and protect from individual operations failing (for instance attempting to do gets in a loop on a cluster with a node failing may give you `RequestCancelledException`s and `TimeoutException`s). What the SDK will pick up is a change in the topology of the cluster: has a node been marked as failed over? Has a node been removed and the cluster rebalanced? If a node isn't manually or automatically failed over, the SDK will still try to contact it and give you timeouts.

Comment: you probably want to refer to the documentation on cluster maintenance and server maintenance concepts : http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Tasks/cluster-maintenance.html and http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Tasks/maintenance-server-node.html